# Plotly Treemap Not Rendering

Tags: r, plotly

I am attempting to create an interactive treemap using `plotly`. When I run my code I get a blank screen. I'm not sure why the code is not working. Any ideas how to fix whatever I am doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 labels = c("Owners' Equivalent Rent of Residences", 
       "Rent of Primary Residence",
       "New Vehicles",
       "Used Cars and Trucks", 
       "Cereals And Bakery Products",
       "Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair", 
       "Airline Fares",
       "Apparel", 
       "Alcoholic Beverages",
       "Hospital Services",
       "Tobacco and Smoking", 
       "Physicians Services", 
       "Gasoline All Types",
       "Electricity", 
       "Utility (Piped) Gas Services",
       "Nonalcoholic Beverages and Beverage Materials",
       "Food Away From Home", 
       "Meats Poultry Fish and Eggs", 
       "Fruits and Vegetables", 
       "Dairy and Related Products",
       "Cereals And bakery Products", 
       "Other Foods at Home")
parents = NA

fig <- plot_ly(
type='treemap',
labels=labels,
values= c(6.7, 6.9, 1.3, 3.8, 3.4, 8.5, 12.1, 1.1, 2.9, 
        6.3, 7.7, 0.7, 8.9, 3.4, 10.4, 2.9, 5.3, 0.1, 0.4, 
        1.4, 3.4, 3.3),
 textinfo="label+value+percent parent+percent entry+percent root",
 domain=list(column=0))
 fig
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you did not provide the `parents=`, i.e. move `parents=NA` inside `plot_ly()`:

```r
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(
  type = "treemap",
  labels = labels,
  parents = NA,
  values = c(
    6.7, 6.9, 1.3, 3.8, 3.4, 8.5, 12.1, 1.1, 2.9,
    6.3, 7.7, 0.7, 8.9, 3.4, 10.4, 2.9, 5.3, 0.1, 0.4,
    1.4, 3.4, 3.3
  ),
  textinfo = "label+value+percent parent+percent entry+percent root",
  domain = list(column = 0)
)
fig
```

[image]